# How to make a variable in mongoose regular expression?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need a way to implement a variable pattern in mongoose:

```
router.get('/search/:name', async(req, res) => {
    name = req.params.name;
    const products = await Product.find({ name: /.*name*/i }).limit(10);
    res.send(products);
});
```

I want to be able to change the name variable.

Comment: you can build a string and pass it to `new RegExp()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Template literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [**RegExp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor

```js
let name = 'xyz'
let reg = `.*${name}.*`
let regex = new RegExp(reg,'i')

console.log(regex)
```